# How to replace regex pattern hh:mm:ss with hh:mm in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, time

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I have a csv file with different time formats as follows:
`hh:mm` and `hh:mm:ss`

An extract of the file looks like this:

```
column_name
00:00:00
01:00:00
05:00
02:00:00
03:00:00
06:00
...
23:00:00
00:00:00
```

I have the following regex expression to match all those times
`[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}`

My question is how do I get rid of the colon and the seconds (`:ss`) for the `hh:mm:ss` formats but keep the `hh:mm` format the same. Essentially changing only one of the formats from
`hh:mm:ss` to `hh:mm` so that they are all in the format `hh:mm` in a python script?

I tried using this line:

```
df['column_name'] = [re.sub(r'[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}', r'[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}', str(x)) for x in df['column_name']]
```

But this changed all the times to this `[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}`

I also tried just using slicing such as `[:-3]` but I could not get it to work:

```
df['column_name'] = [re.sub(r'[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}', [:-3], str(x)) for x in df['column_name']]
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you

**EDIT**
I previously thought @RJ Adriaansen answer was correct but upon closer inspection it also changed the `hh:mm` formats which need to be kept the same, which means that it had to use regex, therefore @Haleemur Ali answer was the one that solved it for me.

Comment: Sure, I've turned it into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use regex to tackle this, use capture groups:

```py
df.column_name.str.replace(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', r'\1:\2', regex=True)
```

to define a capture group, you enclose it in parenthesis. you can then refer to the captured string using the group index (starting with one).

also, important to note that since the groups are referred as `\<group-number>`, a raw regex string needs to be used.

Comment: Thank you @Haleemur Ali, I thought I needed to use regex but it turns out I just didn't know how to do it, I apologize for my lack of experience but thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: yes, for this case, a regex brings you unnecessary complexity, the other answer has more appropriate solutions

Comment: your answer was correct actually because I only wanted the changes to match on that specific regex pattern not the other ```hh:mm``` patterns, so your answer helped me achieve the goal, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the string with [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str[:-3]
```

Or:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.rsplit(':', 1).str[0]
```